# Vue Router beforeRouteEnter API call response not 'working'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I cannot see why the function is not returning its call back correctly.

I have a list of vehicle on one route and then another route to display that vehicles resource.

This is what I have in my Single file component for the single vehicle resource:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            vehicle: null,
            error: null
        }
    },
    created() {

    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {

        function getVehicle(id) {
            console.log('called');
            return axios.get(`/api/v1/vehicles/${id}`);
        }

        getVehicle(to.params.id, (err, vehicle) => {
            console.log('response');
            next(vm => vm.setData(err, vehicle))
        });
    },
    methods: {
        setData (err, vehicle) {
            if (err) {
                this.error = err.toString();
            } else {
                this.vehicle = vehicle;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

This issue is that when clicking a vehicle link, the API call is correctly made and returning a valid response but yet the next() method isn't called and the console log for 'response' isn't shown neither but the 'called' one is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the logic behind it, but had to use .then() for my getVehicle response before it would work. So changed to:

```
getVehicle(to.params.id).then( response => {
    next( vm =>
        vm.setData(response)
    );
});
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. [`to.params`](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/route-object.html#route-object-properties) should not contain promises

Comment: @Phil Good spot, its late! :D Have just added the correct usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will work with a function inside the beforeRouteEnter guard. Instead try call the axios get method like

```
let data = axios.get('/api/v1/vehicles/${to.params.id})
next(vm.setData(err, data))
```

This should work